# SoundCloud App Registration Form Broken

Tags: soundcloud

Anyone else having trouble with the SoundCloud app registration form? I know it's a Google form but I was wondering if anyone else was having an issue. Whenever I fill out the form it says 2 fields are missing. I refill ever field and the same error occurs. All I need is a redirect URI :( . Thanks

Comment: What's the redirect URI that you're trying to use?

Comment: turn:// is the callback i want!